# How can I log a linux command's process tree?

Tags: linux, logging, ps

I'm trying to track the usage of a certain command so I want to log its parents (to see what is actually using it)

Solaris has "ptree" which would be pretty easy to parse and log:

```
# ptree 4198
4198  /usr/bin/perl -S /sample.pl
  4228  /usr/bin/java -server -cp /sample.java
```

Linux doesn't seem to have an equivalent.  I've tried using "pstree" and "ps -auxf" and others without much success.

Comment: `pstree` seems fine for this. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: For one thing, when specifying a process, it only shows the processes from it on down (not the ancestors).  ptree gives you the whole hierarchy.

Comment: Did you miss the `-s` option in the man page?

Comment: Our pstree version does not have the -s unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pstree` seems fine for this.

Consider:

```
$ pstree -p 3281
nginx(3281)─┬─nginx(3282)
            ├─nginx(3283)
            ├─nginx(3284)
            ├─nginx(3285)
            ├─nginx(3286)
            └─nginx(3287)
```

And use `-s` to see parents:

```
$ pstree -p -s 3287
systemd(1)───nginx(3281)───nginx(3287)
```

Comment: Just a note: The version of `pstree` coming with CentOS 6 doesn't support the `-s` option (CentOS 7 has it).

Comment: @Sven Aha, I knew there would be a down side to moving to EL7 rapidly... :)

Comment: Our pstree version does not have the -s unfortunately.

Comment: That's bad news. I'll leave this here, though, for others with the same question, and for later when you migrate to a more modern Linux. :)

Comment: I'll accept this answer as its the only thing I've found so far, even though it only works for newer versions (it will slowly become even more correct over time!)